# Running Docker Interactive Shell

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, drone.io

I am trying to run interactive shell for an image which I am running using docker-compose.

I tried docker-run and docker-exec

```
xyz@abc:~$ sudo docker exec -it 235197ff4f0e /bin/bash
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory"

xyz@abc:~$ sudo docker run -it  drone/drone:0.7 /bin/bash
No help topic for '/bin/bash'
```

Trying to generate ssh key inside drone, so that i can clone from private repositories.

Comment: The answer by @larsks is the correct answer, however, I wanted to expand on the fact that drone does not clone your repository inside the `drone/drone` image. Therefore adding an SSH key to the `drone/drone` image will not have any impact. Instead you should use drone secrets (see the official docs) to register a secret key with your repository that you can then use to clone private git+ssh repositories at runtime. Or use git+https to clone dependencies which drone typically supports with zero configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things going on here.  I'd like to take a look at the second error first:

The `drone/drone` image is configured to automatically run the `/drone` command (which you can determine by using `docker inspect` and looking for the `Entrypoint` key).  So if you run:

```
docker run drone/drone:0.7 help
```

You end up running, inside the container:

```
drone help
```

And of course, if you run:

```
docker run drone/drone:0.7 /bin/bash
```

You are running, in the container:

```
drone /bin/bash
```

Hence the error message you are seeing ("No help topic for '/bin/bash'"), because you are passing an unrecognized option to the the `drone` command.

---

The first error is much simpler.  Your error message is:

```
 exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

That seems pretty clear.  There is no `/bin/bash`.  In fact, if you inspect the contents of the image, you'll see that there is only a minimal filesystem.  The easiest way to look is by starting a container, then using `docker export`, like this:

```
$ docker run drone/drone:0.7 help
[...output doesn't matter...]
$ docker export $(docker ps -lq) | tar tf -
```

Which shows you:

```
.dockerenv
dev/
dev/console
dev/pts/
dev/shm/
drone
etc/
etc/hostname
etc/hosts
etc/mtab
etc/resolv.conf
etc/ssl/
etc/ssl/certs/
etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
proc/
sys/
```

There's no `/bin/bash`, no `ssh`, no `git`, etc, so you're not going to have much luck with your current plan.  You may want to consider cloning the remote repositories on your host and then exposing them to your container using a host volume mount (`-v /host/path:/container path`), or building a custom image that contains the tooling you need.

Comment: This answer is spot on. Note that there is a `drone/drone:0.8-alpine` image that can be used if one needs a shell for debugging purposes.